# Text scroller using javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried implementing the text scroller and it did not appear. What's the problem?

I based it here and followed the steps :
http://javascript.internet.com/text-effects/news-scroller.html

Do you guys have any idea of text scroller aside from this? Something that works like movie credits. :)

Comment: It is fairly impossible to tell what went wrong. Perhaps you did not copy the right files or whatever. We are good but not clairvoyant. There are millions of scrollers out there. And here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vertical+scroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down" scrollamount="2" height="100" width="350">
  hello!
  </marquee>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you desire for a `jQuery` *Plugin*:

- [jQuery Scroller v1.0](http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_scroller/)
- [jQuery Marquee](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html)

And if you already using some other [JSLib](http://www.google.com.pk/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=lUG&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=js+library&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) there is a independent script of vertical scrolling:

- [Vertical Scrolling Text](http://www.news-scroller.com/html-scrolling-text.html)